# Understanding Heroku's database storage

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Heroku PG Yellow DB, which has a storage capacity of 64 GB. However my instance's data size is currently over 200 GB. Is there a difference between data size and storage capacity? If not, shouldn't it stop storing data in the DB post 64 GB?

Comment: What do you mean by your "instance's data size"? Where do you see this value, or otherwise obtain it?

Comment: I'm using Heroku's postgres extension, by going to the extension's page on heroku I'm getting these values

Comment: @Projjol, could you post the output of `heroku pg:info`?

Comment: @GregNavis pasted it here https://www.pastiebin.com/586500ad1459c

Comment: Interesting! I found [another person having a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762212/heroku-postgres-data-size-vs-storage-capacity). @Projjol, how much do they charge you for the database?

Comment: 50$ a month, the way it should be for a standard-0 plan :)

Answer (score 0):

200GB is including the reserved space for indexation and other performance related tasks and for future data.
If you click on "Capture Backup" You'll see the actual storage size you're using.